# Is there a way to merge multiple k-mer count outputs from JELLYFISH tool?

Tags: r, bash, dplyr

I need some help to merge multiple <files.jf>.

Default outputs of a jellyfish k-mer count are files with the k-mer and the relative counts. In my case they are files that have a very large size (even 150-200Gb).
Suppose I have multiple jf files, file1.jf file2.jf file3.jf and so on, of different size and therefore also different row lengths (it is possible that a k-mer in one sample does not exist in another, and so in that case I would like to add an NA value).

i.e. jeffyfish dump file1.jf

```
>2
AGGGTGGATTACACCCACA
>1
CGGGAAGCCATTGGGTAAA
>1
CCCAACCATTTTCTTAACC
>1
ACACCTGTTATGTTTACCA
>1
GTTAATTTTTTAAGTGGGA
```

i.e. jeffyfish dump file2.jf

```
>1
ACTCCTCCCTTGGCAGTAG
>1
CACCAGGCTGAGAAAAGTG
>1
TCTTTACCTAAAAAACAAA
```

i.e. jeffyfish dump file3.jf

```
>1
CCTTTATCCCTGAGACCAC
>1
AAATGCAAGAGAAACAAAG
>2
TCTTTACCTAAAAAACAAA
>1
ACCAAGCAGGTCCATGAGC
>1
GCATGGGGAGAAAGTGCCA
>1
AATTCTCTGGTGCCTGCTC
>1
TCGTTGGGCTGAGTCATCA
```

Actually the file shows up with the number >n in the row above and the sequence in the row below, so for all files (but here I can't represent them in column).

I would like to obtain an outputs like this

| 19-mer | file1 | file2 | file3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AGGGTGGATTACACCCACA | 2 | NA | NA |
| CGGGAAGCCATTGGGTAAA | 1 | NA | NA |
| CCCAACCATTTTCTTAACC | 1 | NA | NA |
| ACACCTGTTATGTTTACCA | 1 | NA | NA |
| GTTAATTTTTTAAGTGGGA | 1 | NA | NA |
| ACTCCTCCCTTGGCAGTAG | NA | 1 | NA |
| CACCAGGCTGAGAAAAGTG | NA | 1 | NA |
| TCTTTACCTAAAAAACAAA | NA | 1 | 2 |
| CCTTTATCCCTGAGACCAC | NA | NA | 1 |
| AAATGCAAGAGAAACAAAG | NA | NA | 1 |
| ACCAAGCAGGTCCATGAGC | NA | NA | 1 |
| GCATGGGGAGAAAGTGCCA | NA | NA | 1 |
| AATTCTCTGGTGCCTGCTC | NA | NA | 1 |
| TCGTTGGGCTGAGTCATCA | NA | NA | 1 |

Could anyone tell me how to do it? Scripts in bash, R or other solutions with other commands (i.e. join bash command or others) are fine.
I also tried with jellyfish merge but it dowsn't work due two the different length of the files.

IMPORTANT: In some files the same sequence may also have been found, in which case I would like the sample / file count to be printed for both.

Comment: This seems fairly challenging - with such large files you'd want to think carefully about the joining algorithm/process.  Can you afford to have everything in memory? Would someone on the biostars/bioconductor list be able to help out?

Comment: Hi Ben , thank you for the answer. I guess to have the required space since I'm working in a cluster (in the worst case I could do a number of files at a time). 
I was thinking to use the source code in count_in_file.cc (https://github.com/gmarcais/Jellyfish/tree/master/examples/count_in_file) that performs the steps that I would like but I can't find any feedback about it.

Comment: I would be tempted to figure out how to load these as tables into a lightweight SQL database (might require pre-processing?) and then use `dtplyr` to do joins ...

Comment: You can use the dump files (in the fasta format) read them in a dictionary (Python) using the kmers (strings) as keys and the headers as the values and them using pandas to make that dict as a dataframe.